# Are STL associative containers containing containers a performance issue?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, containers, c++03

In my scenario, I have a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<cCustomClass> >`, but the same question applies to `std::set`. These vectors can become quite large (more than 100000 elements), so I am concerned if vectors are reallocated or copied if I add more elements to the map.

The central question is: Will the map copy the large vectors at some point and if yes, does it have a cost proportional to `std::vector::capacity()`?

If the answer to both is yes, what are my options? My first solution would be to use a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<cCustomClass> * >` and (or smart pointers), but I wonder if this is necessary.

I use C++03. If the answer depends on the Standard, I appreciate any remarks about it.

Comment: Inserting new elements into a map (or a set) or removing elements doesn't invalidate iterators, indicating that the contents will not be moved or copied. There's no absolute guarantee though.

Comment: No, the `map` will not just randomly copy elements around. Could you show some code that performs an unnecessary copy?

Comment: can you be more specific? How large is "quite large"? What do you want to do with the map?

Comment: I think only if you [insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) an already populated big vector into a map, there would be a performance issue, as move-insert is only available since C++11. So when inserting such a big vector, the whole thing would be copied into the map. But this will only affect the one map item you are inserting, existing map items won't be copied around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the map copy the large vectors at some point

No. `map`, `set` and the other associative containers are node-based. Nodes are allocated independently for each entry, connected by pointers, and don't need to be copied or re-allocated when the container grows, shrinks, rebalances itself etc. etc.

Your guarantee of this is the *iterator invalidation requirements* on various containers. Compare

- [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)

  > No iterators or references are invalidated

  If iterators aren't invalidated, the element they point to must keep its location in memory, so inserting into a map can't requiring copying or moving any existing elements.
- [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

  > If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()`, all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

  If iterators *are* invalidated, the element *may have* moved, copying or moving the value. Specifically for a vector, elements *after* an insertion *must* be moved/copied to make space for the new element.

  If the vector needed reallocation to grow, *all* elements must be moved/copied to the new allocated region.

It's worth noting, although it doesn't really affect you with `map`, that modern compilers will *move* elements where possible. Your large vector would be moved, for example, which is much cheaper than copying it - if you can update to C++11 or later, that is.